# Desaturated images colored on hover?

Tags: media

Is there a clean, "hands-free" way to have a ticker full of logotypes desaturated in normal view, but colored on hover? Or should I prepare CSS sprites by myself and go the "dirty" way?

Comment: Maybe you could ask to migrate your question to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ? It is not really Drupal-specific.

Comment: not necessarily, I know how to do that the raw CSS/JS way. but maybe there's a module that facilitates the process. Maybe someone has implemented it and can share Drupal how-to.

Comment: Do you mean something like in that post but implemented as a contrib module ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6891607/945548

Comment: Yep, preferably. Although I'm afraid that might be difficult, as I just saw another thread on the desaturated images not working in D7. Oh well, looks like I'm going to dig up the dirt again :) Thanks for looking up the issue.

Comment: I agree that this might be address in terms of Drupal. I've been looking a solution for this. Having a employee page with images of the employees that are black and white and color on hover is a very cool effect which I've been looking for a while now.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question but by now this seems to be the module that you needed:
[Image desaturate formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_desaturate_formatter)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this with [Imagecache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) (included in D7 core) and maybe a few of its fellow modules depending on what you want to achieve exactly.

You setup your image presets and then CSS your hovers to your heart's content.

I've done this many times and it works perfectly, including with dynamic pictures provided in content.